# Setting text background color in Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using Raphael-js to position text on a canvas. Is it possible to have a background color for the text? I would like different text elements to have different backgrounds colors.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background of text is known as "fill" and can be applied using the attr function as follows:

```
paper.text(50, 50, "Example").attr("fill", "#000000");
```

For a full listing of the properties, see the [Raphael Documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#attr)

Comment: fill gives me the color of the text itself, not the background. I would like to keep the text in black and change the background color.

Comment: Ahh I see, badly worded question. You could use rect() with text() on top. They are separate elements and so cannot be achieved with just text().

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is no way to specify background for text, here is how to create rectangle that will serve as a background:

```
var text = canvas.text(p.x, p.y, poly.title).attr(textAttr);
var box = text.getBBox();
var rect = canvas.rect(box.x, box.y, box.width, box.height).attr('fill', 'black');
text.toFront();
```